# Nativescript button inside listivew unique binding property

Tags: button, data-binding, binding, unique, nativescript

I have listview on nativescript layout and on every item  there's button inside.

```
<Button text="{{ 'someBtn' + unique_id }}" id="{{ load_id }}" tap="someTapEvent"/>
```

I wan't that every button has some stock name and unique id from data added to it. So then I could do `this.set("someBtnunique_id", "Actual text")`

I don't want to mess unique_id field, I want every button to be unique with binding with it'w own property name constructed from data which consists id.

(I'm using Javascript and viewmodel)

Comment: What is load_id ? Because there is no way to get direct reference to element by it's text. You will need to set id="{{ 'someBtn' + unique_id}}"
and then set text like this `page.getViewById("someBtnunique_id").set("text","Actual Text")`

Comment: yeah, this make's sense, I try this out.

Comment: `text="{{ 'someBtn' + unique_id }}"` this won't concat as you expected. For example `unique_id = 99` then the button text will actually be `"someBtn99"`. And `someBtn99` will work as a raw text, not a reference so that you can do `this.set("someBtn99", "Actual text")`

Comment: Yep, true. One thing that I need to do now is to set text from viewmodel using button id. Since there's as many buttons as listview has items I don't know how I get them all from viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

The property `text="{{ 'someBtn' + unique_id }}"` won't concat as you expected. For example `unique_id = 99` then the button text will actually be `"someBtn99"`. And `someBtn99` will work as a raw text, not a reference so that you can do `this.set("someBtn99", "Actual text")`. If you still want to use `this.set` and if you have the string `someBtn` dynamically, I suggest:

In XML:

```
<Button text="{{ someBtnUniqueId }}"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
get unique_id(): string {
    return some_id;
}

get someBtn(): string {
    return someBtn;
}

this[this.someBtn + this.unique_id] = "blah blah";
```

Later on, you will have the `someBtnUniqueId` as a property so that you can change it to anything you want

Comment: I think Terhoraj want to set text of Button with help of `someBtnXX`

Comment: Just to clear things. I never want to change actual load_id property. I wan't to use load_id added to some static name. Use this combination to set buttons texts based on other changing variable states. All this has to happen from view model.

Comment: My answer didn't touch the `load_id`. For your information, you can add a property to a static name by the same way as I have mentioned above which is : `this[string1 + string2 + string3] = blahblah`